# How to combine std::str::lines and std::io::lines?

Tags: generics, iterator, rust, traits

I want to write a function to parse text, but the text may come from external file or an internal `&str`. The `parse` function may go like this:

```
fn parse(lines: GenericLinesGenerator) {
   for line in lines {
       // parse content
   }
}
```

... and it can be invoked like this:

```
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::fs::File;
let fin = BufReader::new(File::open("info.txt").expect("not found"));
parse(TransformFromIO(fin.lines()))
```

or

```
let content: &'static str = "some\nlong\ntext";
parse(TransformFromStr(content.lines()))
```

Is it possible to implement such a `parse` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two iterators don't produce the same values:

```
impl<B: BufRead> Iterator for io::Lines<B> {
    type Item = Result<String>;
}
```

```
impl<'a> Iterator for str::Lines<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;
}
```

You have to handle that difference somehow. The most important difference is that `io::Lines` can *fail*. Your program has to decide how to deal with that; I've chosen to just abort the program.

The next thing you need to do is to accept any type that can be converted into an iterator, and the value yielded from the iterator has to be converted to a type that you can deal with. It appears that `&str` is the common denominator.

This is solved by using [`IntoIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) and [`Borrow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html):

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn parse<I>(lines: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Borrow<str>,
{
    for line in lines {
        println!("line: {}", line.borrow());
    }
}

fn main() {
    parse("alpha\nbeta\ngamma".lines());

    println!("----");

    let f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("Couldn't open");
    let b = BufReader::new(f);
    parse(b.lines().map(|l| l.expect("Bad line!")));
}
```

Check [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) section on [`where` clauses](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/traits.html#where-clause) for more information about *trait bounds*.

Comment: It's surprising that you don't need to implement any new trait for such kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `Borrow` bound in the `parse` function will allow you to borrow `&str`, but if you need `String` values, a better approach is to use `Cow`.

Using `line.borrow().to_string()` to obtain a `String` value will always allocate, even when `parse` is called with lines from file (in this case, `lines.map` produces `String`).

Using `line.into_owned()` will allocate when called with lines from an `&str`, but will not allocate when called with lines from file (will just unwrap the `String` value passed to `Cow::Owned`).

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::iter::IntoIterator;
use std::fs::File;

fn parse<'a, I>(lines: I)
    where I: IntoIterator,
          I::Item: Into<Cow<'a, str>>
{
    for line in lines {
        let line: Cow<'a, str> = line.into();
        let line: String = line.into_owned();
        // or
        let line = line.into().into_owned()
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let fin = BufReader::new(File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("cannot open file"));
    parse(fin.lines().map(|r| r.expect("file read failed")));

    let content: &'static str = "some\nlong\ntext";
    parse(content.lines());
}
```